# Is there a way to intercept the response of an ajax http request made by a flash object via javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, http

I want want to intercept the response for an ajax request made inside a flash object via javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: The only way to do this would be with some kind of browser add-on.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for debugging, yes you can. Firefox extension Firebug [Firebug website](http://getfirebug.com/) will show you the connection.

For windows, Fiddler ([Fiddler Website](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) will do it too.

Comment: I mean live, with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In Mozilla Firefox, install addons "Firebug" and "Flash firebug".


After installation, open firebug and click on "Net" tab, select "All".


You will see the requests as well as their responses for all the requests made to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is a good choice to trace HTTP requests and responses, including Ajax.
If you prefer raw packets, wireshark is another choice, but requires more knowledge about network protocols.